# How to compare two arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I've got two arrays and I want to compare them and find all differences. Arrays looks like:

- GroupName
- Members
- User
- User
- Group
- User

Etc...

When loop find "Members" it should take previous element as group name (because few groups are members of other groups).

My actual code:

```
for(auto a = 0; a < 100; a++)
{
    const auto data1 = TabList1[a];

    for(auto b = 0; b < 100; b++)
    {
        const auto data2 = TabList2[b];

        if (data1 == 'Members')
        {
            a = a - 1;
            string = TabList1[a];
            a = a + 1;
        }
        if (data1 != data2)
        {
            println "Not match!";
        }
    }
}
```

Of course it's more like pseudocode. Anyone can tell what is wrong in this code?

Comment: Why do you think something's wrong? Determine that and take it from there.

Comment: By using the [comparison operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp) of the [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) object.

Comment: I mean - is it good way to compare this two array (taking data, etc)?

Comment: Don't claim that something is "actual code" when it isn't.

Comment: Array of _what_? Just strings? Does the relative order of groups matter? It sounds like you need a data model that represents the information you are working with, rather than just working with un-typed lists of strings.

Comment: String of course. Arrays look like GRUPONAME->Members->User->Group->User->User->User->GroupName->Members->User...

Answer (score 0):

"I've got two arrays and I want to compare them and find all differences."

That should be pretty simple. This assumes that your arrays have the same size:

```
for(auto i = std::mismatch(std::begin(TabList1), std::end(TabList1), std::begin(TabList2);
    i.first != std::end(Tablist1);
    i = std::mismatch(std::next(i.first), std::end(TabList1), std::next(i.second)){
    //i is a pair of iterators.
    //The first iterator points to the element of TabList1 that mismatched
    //The second iterator points to the element of TabList2 that mismatched
    //You should operate on those pointers here.
}
```

"When loop find "Members" it should take previous element as group name (because few groups are members of other groups)."

This assumes that `TabList1` contains at least 1 element.

```
for(auto i = std::find(std::next(std::begin(TabList1)),std::end(TabList1), "Members");
    i != std::end(TabList1);
    i = std::find(std::next(i), std::end(TabList1), "Members")){
    if(*std::prev(i) != "GroupName"){
        //std::prev(i) holds an iterator to what should have been a "GroupName"
        //i holds an iterator to "Members"
        //You should operate on these pointers here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to verify this, because in future I want to change "Not match!" message for "User X was find/wasn't find in group Y"

Comment: @adam.cziker Both of these methods seem like stuff that should only happen in debug or to validate user input. If you are going to check both of these everytime you would probably be better of with a simple: `for(auto i = 0; i < std::distance(std::begin(TabList1), std::end(TabList1)); ++i)` I've shown you code you could use if you're validating them separately though.